# あるページのテキストリンクを全てクリックしたい

Tags: python3, selenium

あるページのリンクを自動で全てクリックにしたいのですが、
現段階では、ひとつとしてクリックイベントが発生されられない状態です。

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')
elements[0].click // とりあえず最初のaタグだけども
```

根本的になにかおかしいでしょうか？

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time


url = "http://www.jma.go.jp/jp/yoho/"


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.implicitly_wait(60)
actions = ActionChains(driver)

driver.get(url)
elements = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')

elements[0].click

time.sleep(10)

driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`elements[0].click`のところは関数呼び出しなので引数がなくてもかっこが必要です

`elements[0].click()` としてください

Comment: クリックは成功しましたが、ページを移るとエラーになりました。selenium.common.exc‌​eptions.StaleElement‌​ReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document ページを移った場合は取得したElementsは失われるのでしょうか？